# iOS devices without Internet to capture current location

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation, location, cllocationmanager

As far as I have searched, iOS devices without internet (WiFi) are struggling to acquire current location when GPS is the only option.

Is it possible to get current location in that situation, I mean using only GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it does automatically, if no WiFi is enabled it should automatically trigger the GPS, it takes a long time because if no location data is cached it starts to search for satellites.
If you want to display and error message, you can use a timer, if after X seconds no location is obtained just stop updates and show an alert to the user.
A great difference in time is made by the `desiredAccuracy`, if you set a lower accuracy even if when the GPS is on it will require less to get your position.

Comment: This is what happening in my case. It was trying to get location, but it always fails. I will try setting lower accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by struggle?

> Is it possible to get current location in that situation, I mean using
>   only GPS?

yes, perfectly

Comment: How to get that, If I turn of WiFi, the device is not able to get location.

Comment: If you turn off wifi (not by entering airplane mode) everything should "continue" to work normally. 
If the location service is working properly in wifi, then it should work without wifi, unless GPS can't detect you, like you're in a cave very deep underground

Comment: Thats the problem, the GPS can't detect me if the WiFi is turned off. Its keeps on searching and it always fails to detect current location. Works fine with Wifi connection.